# How to chown/chmod all files in current directory?

Tags: linux, chmod, chown

I am trying to change the ownership and permissions of some files (and directories) in the current directory. I tried this:

```
chown username:groupname .
```

...expecting that it would affect all the files in the current directory, but instead only affected the directory that I am in (which is the opposite of what I want to do). I want to change it on all the files without affecting the current directory that I am in.

How can I chown and chmod all files in current directory?

Comment: @Shi I think it's a fair question. Reading that man page wouldn't help. [Globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) is not part of `chmod`. It is builtin to the shell. Also reading documentation on globbing sucks the life out of you (I spent way to much time figuring out all the zsh's features).

Comment: @djf: `chown -R user:group .`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You want to use `chown username:groupname *`, and let the shell expand the `*` to the contents of the current directory. This will change permissions for all files/folders in the current directory, but not the contents of the folders.

You could also do `chown -R username:groupname .`, which would change the permissions on the current directory, and then recurse down inside of it and all subfolders to change the permissions.

`chown -R username:groupname *` will change the permissions on all the files and folders recursively, while leaving the current directory itself alone. This style and the first style are what I find myself using most often.

Comment: @Andrew Be on your guard though, he can be both friend and foe to the weary or unprepared.

Comment: Also, beware of the dangers of the period. As it is placed right next to the almight "/" on the keyboard. A simple typo can easily turn `chown -R username:groupname .` into `chown -R username:groupname /`. Making a 2 second task a 2 day nightmare.

Comment: @Tom That's why I should probably start using `-v` on all my recursive commands, but too lazy

Comment: Just upvoted as the best and most concise anwser, although I'd be specific and name the directory, just to avoid a slip of the keyboard: `chown -R username:groupname directoryname`

Comment: This doesn't do all of the files, it ignores the dot files, which were the ones I wanted to chown anyway (the git files needed to be owned by my user so...)

I was able to fix it with `chown -R username:groupname ./.*`

Comment: chown scott:scott *
chown: invalid option -- ' '
???

Answer (score 15):

I think you want this:

`chown username:groupname *`

If you also want to recursively change subdirectories, you'll need the `-R` (`-r` is deprecated) switch:

`chown -R username:groupname *`

Answer (score 1):

`chown` is great if you are a superuser. I had an issue where someone else had run `make` in my directory, and now owned some files that I could not modify. Here is my workaround which handles files and directories, although it leaves the directories lying around with suffix `.mkmeowner` if it can't delete them.

- The following script changes ownership of files and directories passed to it to be owned by the current user,
  attempting to work around permission issues
  by making a new copy of every directory or file
  not owned by the current user, deleting (or trying to delete)
  the original file, and renaming appropriately.
- The intent is for it to be an abbreviation for "make me owner". I don't use underscores because they are a pain to type.

Examples:

```
% mkmeowner .

% mkmeowner dirpath1 dirpath2
```

- It requires the following script `mkmeownerone` to be in your path.

mkmeowner:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "x$1" == "x-h" ] || [ "x$1" == "x--help" ] && cat << END && exit 0
Usage: $0 dirorfile [direorfile2 ...]:
    change ownership of directories or files to current user.
    Current user must have permissions to read those and write to owner directory.
END
mkmeownerone=`which mkmeownerone`
for d in $*; do
    find "$d" -not -user `whoami` -exec $mkmeownerone {} \;
done
```

mkmeownerone:

```
#!/bin/bash
# change ownership of one file or directory
f="$1"
expr match "${f}" '.*\.mkmeowner$' > /dev/null && exit 1 # already tried to do this one
if mv -f "$f" "${f}.mkmeowner"; then
    cp -pr "${f}.mkmeowner" "$f" && rm -rf "${f}.mkmeowner"
    exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

Comment: (1) We prefer answers that include some explanation.  I was taken by surprise when I read your scripts and saw what they did, because your introductory paragraph didn’t give me a clue. (2) You forgot to mention that the user must put `mkmeownerone` into the search PATH.  `mkmeowner` will blow up if that isn’t done. (3) Please learn how (i.e., when and where) to use quotes in shell commands and scripts.  Saying `${f}` isn’t a useful alternative; see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/23408#286525 "${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does …").  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) If you run your script on a directory, it will potentially copy every file in that directory twice. (5) `expr` is antiquated.  It’s more efficient to do simple string matching in the shell; bash also supports regular expression matching.  For that matter, you could do the filename test in `find.` (6) Your `expr match` command tests whether `${f}` ends with `mkmeowner`, not whether it ends with `.mkmeowner`.  Therefore, the script will not work on itself.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Now, arguably, this is a good thing — you don’t want to be moving and potentially deleting a script while it’s running.  (It’s not necessarily going to cause a problem, but it can be messy.)  But you should understand (and document) special cases like that.  (7) You might want to use underscores in multi-word strings.  `dirorfile` is hard to read and understand (compare to `dir_or_file`), and when I saw `mkmeowner`, my first thought was of a cat (`mk` + **``meow``** + `ner`).

Comment: Thanks for the notes Scott.
1. I thought I did have an explanation but let me be more explicit.
2. good point. I had captured that in my original script, but took out the reference.
3. I've been writing shell scripts for 30 years, but sure, I'll try to learn more.
4. Yes it does. On purpose because if I don't own the directory, I cannot delete it. I can mention that.
5. Yah I'm old fashioned, but expr still works pretty well
6. ha good point.
7. I might, I think I I get some artistic license though, as underscores are not a rule. I need a script that makes meows!

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with ${f}, right? It's just a little longer than necessary. It's a format I use often because I may want to use a variable to make a longer string like ${f}.mkmeowner, and I don't have to remember whether $f.heck means ${f}+heck or ${f.heck}

Comment: (3) Did you read the link?  If `f` contains a space (e.g., `fat cat`), then `"$f"` (with quotes) is `fat cat`, but `${f}` (without quotes) is two separate words: `fat` and `cat`.  No, the braces don’t hurt, but they leave you unprotected.   (7) If you dislike underscores, you can use CamelCase (`MkMeOwner`) or snakeCase (`mkMeOwner`).    :-)    ⁠

Comment: Well, my point #4 was that, if `bob-dir` contains `bob-file` (both owned by ``bob``), then the script will `mv -f bob-dir bob-dir.mkmeowner` and `cp -pr bob-dir.mkmeowner bob-dir` (which will copy `bob-dir.mkmeowner/bob-file` to `bob-dir/bob-file`, making it owned by you) and then (at least potentially) ***also*** do `mv -f bob-file bob-file.mkmeowner` and `cp -pr bob-file.mkmeowner bob-file` (in the newly created `bob-dir` directory).  I’ll admit, it’s not obvious to me how to fix that.

Comment: Actually I don't like shift keys...

Comment: #4. huh. ya. thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the owner of the current directory too. None of the above `chown .` and `chown *` worked. I had to pass in the full directory path:

```
$ chown -R nobody: "$PWD"
```

In the above `nobody` is the user I need. Group is omitted because it's optional when it equals the user.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change `username:groupname` of all files in the current directory is to work with a subshell:

```bash
chown username:groupname $(find . -name "[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

The bash built-in command `find` is used with a regular-expression `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` in a subshell `$()` which can form the basis of more complex administrative tasks.